# apache solr 4.8.1, inconsistancy in number of docs in a cloud

Tags: solr

we are using solr 4.8.1 cloud (1shard with four nodes)for our environment. There is an inconsistency in latest data coming into three nodes.

Example, we are commiting data to solr1 and that data is getting replicated to solr3 after 5 minutes, where as solr 2 and solr 4 gets it immediately.

Also this behaviour changes when we restart the cluster

so if X was lagging after restart it may not lag again

Any ideas about the issue?

Comment: the problem is unclear, could you try to describe it more precisely?

Comment: There is one shard with 4 nodes, when a record is inserted into cloud, 1st, 2nd, 3rd nodes will get that record immediately. But when we check on 4th nodes we don't see the record, it will be available only after 10 minutes. We check that record in each node by using distrib=false in the query. Hope this is clear.